# Trying to convert db_fetch_object for Drupal 7

Tags: database

I am trying to convert a line of code from Drupal 6 for Drupal 7

```
for ($i = 0; $order = db_fetch_object($result); ++$i) {
```

Above is what it is -- and below is what I made it

```
for ($i = 0; foreach ($result as $order); ++$i) {
```

BUT . . . I get a parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting
>   ';' in / [PATH TO FILE] on line 483

Which is this

```
for ($i = 0; foreach ($result as $order); ++$i) {
```

SQL syntax checkers find no error in the syntax - I only a novice

Comment: Note that you're writing PHP code.  A SQL syntax checker won't help with that.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I am sorry, but explaining why `for ($i = 0; foreach ($result as $order); ++$i)` gives a syntax error is not on-topic here. We suppose you know PHP, and we cannot teach you PHP.

Answer (score 2):

the syntax is incorrect, and the error is correct. If you need to track $i, you could do something like:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($result as $order){
  ...
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Geoff - that worked.  That was my next guess was to declare $i = 0 on a separate line.  The nested function was a problem and I "suspected" the "for" statement was the problem.  I would have missed putting the ++$i on a separate line.  Did you mean to flip the incrementer from pre-increment to post increment ??

Comment: as I wrote it, $i++ or ++$i should have the same effect since it is outside the for loop control - $i++ is the more traditional way of writing it - $i will be incremented by 1 either way before starting the next foreach

Comment: Oh . . . thanks - I did not see that coming !! - or err I missed that distinction of outside the new replaced style of the for loop.  If there is an increment issue I know what to move where